# c++ cygwin and eclipse - binary not found error

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, path-variables

I've spent hours looking up how to fix this problem but nothing has worked. I have eclipse Indigo with CDT and ive downloaded cygwin and packages such as g++, make file, etc. When I try to execute any code I end up with the error `Launch failed. Binary not found.` I've also set the system path C:\cygwin\bin. How can I set up eclipse so I can use it as my IDE for c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, I didn't press the hammer button to build the project first. I've only used eclipse for java and I could just hit run and everything would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading MinGW, and using those compilers.  The `Cygwin` tools require libraries that Eclipse may not load.  The MinGW executables do not require any additional environment like Cygwin does.

Also, in order to use most Cygwin executables, you need to launch the Cygwin environment first.